# What is an informed evaluation of resource availability?

Tags: application, united-states, postdocs, job-search

I am applying for a postdoctoral fellowship at an American University and I have to submit the research proposal. Besides the usual description of my own research, it is written that I must describe the

> resources necessary to conduct the project
>   and an informed evaluation of resource availability.

What does this exactly mean?

Answer (score 6):

"Resources" generally means "money, and things that cost money".  So:

- What resources do you need in order to carry out your research?  This could include equipment, staff, students, travel funding, software, computers, books, use of specialized facilities, etc, etc.
- How are you planning to get those resources and/or the money to pay for them?  Applying for external grants, sharing with collaborators, internal university funding, etc?

Answer (score 6):

It asks you to define or list the resources needed for the project and show that you have considered where those resources may be obtained.